Dropdown menu in folium doesn't work (Python code)
I try to create a choropleth with Folium. The choropleth should show the different growth rates of the countries (lower growth rate = dark green, growth rate > 0 = red). In addition, I would like to have a dropdown menu where I can choose between the different years. The default year should be 2016 (or any other, doesn't matter).
The dataframe is called final_consumption data (columns = COUNTRY, YEAR, PRODUCT, VALUE, GROWTH_RATE).
The colors are still not correct set up, I know. But may main problem is that the dropdown menu doesn't appear and the year is not considered.
Here is the code:
import folium
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import HTML, display
import geopandas as gpd

final_consumption_data = data_completed_coordinates[data_completed_coordinates['PRODUCT'] == 'Final      
consumption']

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
world.to_file("world_countries.geojson", driver='GeoJSON')
geojson_path = "world_countries.geojson"

map_choropleth = folium.Map(tiles='OpenStreetMap', location=[48, 8], zoom_start=2)

choropleth = folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data=geojson_path,
    name='choropleth',
    data=final_consumption_data,
    columns=['COUNTRY', 'GROWTH_RATE'],
    key_on='feature.properties.name',
    fill_color='RdYlGn',
    fill_opacity=0.7,
    line_opacity=0.2,
    legend_name='Consumption growth rate (%)',
    highlight=True
).add_to(map_choropleth)

folium.LayerControl().add_to(map_choropleth)

year_dropdown = widgets.Dropdown(options=final_consumption_data['YEAR'].unique(),
                                 value=2016,
                                 description='Year',
                                 disabled=False,
                                 )


def update_choropleth(year):
    # print(f"Selected year: {year}")
    filtered_data = final_consumption_data[final_consumption_data['YEAR'] == year]
    # print(filtered_data.head())
    choropleth.geojson.data = filtered_data
    choropleth.options['name'] = f'Consumption growth rate (%) for year {year}'



year_dropdown.observe(lambda change: update_choropleth(change.new), names='value')

display(year_dropdown)
display(map_choropleth)

map_choropleth.save('choropleth_interactive.html') 

As you can see, I tried some debugging by printing out some steps. The data frame is fine.
But the variable year_dropdown and the function update_choropleth seems to have bugs (even if I tried different ways to program it as you might see).

Please share a minimal, reproducible example. Then please test what you post in a fresh notebook. First attempt to run your code gets a syntax error. Fixing that, I get NameError: name 'data_completed_coordinates' is not defined. It doesn't have to use your data; a toy example is fine if it gives the same behavior as you. However, in order to get help working code makes a big difference.

@Wayne: First of all: Many thanks for having a look! I would share my data, that's not a problem. But how can I attach a csv file?

Probably don't need all your data. Maybe just the top few lines? Anyway, a gist is one option, or see here for other options.

Does this help?
COUNTRY,YEAR,PRODUCT,VALUE,GROWTH_RATE,LATITUDE,LONGITUDE
Argentina,2015,Coal,2747.782,0.0,-35.4468214894951,-65.17536077114173
Argentina,2015,Combustible renewables,1120.509,0.0,-35.4468214894951,-65.17536077114173
Argentina,2015,Distribution losses,-1536.715,0.0,-35.4468214894951,-65.17536077114173
Argentina,2015,Electricity supplied,138361.512,0.0,-35.4468214894951,-65.17536077114173
Argentina,2015,Electricity trade,-770.68,0.0,-35.4468214894951,-65.17536077114173
Argentina,2015,Final consumption,139918.777,0.0,-35.4468214894951,-65.17536077114173

Not quite with the code provided. I cannot see if the dropdown works because I have to change value=2016 to value=2015 to get it to even run with that and then it isn't as you describe. I see the dropdown showing up. Of course, since only one year, I cannot choose other year to see if changes. This is why a minimal, reproducible example is described well in How do I ask a good question? in the first bullet point under 'Help others reproduce the problem'. You are supposed to test and have it working to give what you see. I see a dropdown. ....

 So I'm not sure what you are seeing compared to what I see. You state "But may main problem is that the dropdown menu doesn't appear ". That isn't what I see. I get the dropdown showing up with just one year listed.

I can show you what I see. Go here to start a session served by the MyBinder service. Then in the notebook that comes up, run the first cell. After that completes entirely, restart the kernel and run the second cell. (Actually you can do 'Run All' it seems, but always best to restart kernel after %pip install.)

I'm so sorry about my bad example and bad structure of my question. I'm new here and new in programming. If possible, I'd send you the full data set via mail.
Regarding your comment about what you see. Interesting! Because you see more than I do: I see a map with all the countries with different colors (depending on the growth rate) and a legend. But there is no dropdown menu AND the growth rates seem to be to high, so I assume that all the years are summed up. The map is definitely not combined with a specific year (when I switched the default value 2016 to another one, nothing changes.

More examples:
Lithuania,2016,Wind,1130.001,40.19880917966398,55.284319484766066,23.88064027584349
Lithuania,2017,Combustible renewables,443.346,12.855771898697444,55.284319484766066,23.88064027584349
Lithuania,2017,Distribution losses,913.999,0.7684429053536279,55.284319484766066,23.88064027584349
Lithuania,2017,Electricity supplied,12673.302,2.813650419852287,55.284319484766066,23.88064027584349
Lithuania,2017,Electricity trade,-8677.202,4.860447129909362,55.284319484766066,23.88064027584349
New Zealand,2018,Wind,2047.18204,-0.8743758594642714,-41.662578757158684,172.70192594405574

Maybe that's important: I use PyCharm as IDE.

First. two things based on your most recent comments. With the additional data, I still get only one year. final_consumption_data['YEAR'].unique() results in an array just with 2015. And yes, mentioning your IDE would have been important in your title or at least in your post text to make things accurate.  Let's broaden the scope here for a minute though. Hopefully you've read the advice on 'How do I ask a good question' that I linked to above? You should be endeavoring to fix your post by updating it to include all the stuff I'd advised and the new information. I don't see any effort ...

 being made to do that. The fact that the code has syntax errors and final_consumption_data['YEAR'].unique() results in only one number makes it hard to see that you have been troubleshooting this. This is not an AI-based service. You have to help those trying to help you. Maybe at this point you can put this together and try a new post? Code snippet sharing sites or gists can be used to share large code and files if need be. Usually though a small toy set like you've been slowly developing here is good enough though and fits in the post.

Ok, sorry that I used your time. I didn't see any syntax errors (otherwise I guess I wouldn't have seen any map) and believe it or not, I spent a lot of time in troubleshooting. Thanks for your efforts.

I'm happy to keep helping but it makes it hard that it seems you aren't working along and updating things and there's compounding inconsistencies that I worry are getting further away form the actual issue here. (Inconsistencies may be between my code and yours but I cannot tell because you haven't seemed to try what I've been provided by you or actually update what is provided.) Somehow the map works to do something. And I get that often pasting in the code can introduce things. That is why it is always best to run the code provided separate from your own real resource.

And separate from that is the PyCharm thing. Do other ipywidgets examples in the documentation (and elsewhere) using dropdowns work fine in PyCharm?

I've updated what I have from you to add additional lines to make it have multiple lines that have 'Final consumption'' so it sort of works for now. I see the map change for the three countries. (You can run the updated code now here. ...

 Again, right now it is actually my version of your code.) I'm not sure what your line choropleth.options['name'] = f'Consumption growth rate (%) for year {year}' is supposed to be doing to the map. I don't see a change to the map associated with that; however, maybe I am not looking in the correct place.

Thanks for keep helping. Well, I haven't changed the code that's why I didn't update it. I thought that it might be a good idea to try a different (easier) graph with another library. So, I created one with pyplot - and for some reason the dropdown menu appears.
Then, I tried my code in Jupyter Notebook --> another success: The dropdown menu appears. That means, you might be right with PyCharm. I didn't know that it makes a difference. But: The dropdown menu appears but a click on the years doesn't change the data.
Then I tried different internet browser (Chrome, Edge) - no difference.

Afterwards, I turned off the firewall - no difference.
I tried your provided link. I see the map and the dropdown menu (in the result cell in the kernel) but a click on the years doesn't change the color of the countries/the data (that's why I thought about the firewall...). And: When I open - in your example - the HTML file, no dropdown menu is there.
choropleth.options['name'] = f'Consumption growth rate (%) for year {year}' is used to update the name of the choropleth map when a new year is selected - well, that was at least my plan.

Oh wait, you are right. Those three countries I included come out lit up at the start now. I was adding them individually, progressively to the dataframe and so I thought the map was updating. However, it makes sense. You have the data for the map as final_consumption_data. And in the code final_consumption_data you provided data_completed_coordinates[data_completed_coordinates['PRODUCT'] == 'Final consumption']. So, what is supposed to be happening? Only data for the year? You didn't set that.

Yeah, the column PRODUCT contains lots of electricity production related stuff and the row Final consumption (each COUNTRY with each YEAR has this row with the VALUE for it). A change of the year via dropdown menu should change the growth rate (another column) of the Final consumption for each country for the selected year. Does this make sense / is this understandable?
